# ReactJS upload multiple image in base64 into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to create an `image` uplaoder based on `base64` and I want to get results as an `array` but I got `empty!` array, I know maybe it's a `asynchronous` issue, but I don't know how to use `async, await` in `map` any idea?

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

const fileBase64 = (img) => {
    let result = [...img];

    setUrlImage(img);

    result && result.map(function (img){
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(img);
        fileReader.onloadend = async () => {
            let res = await fileReader.result;
            setArray([...array, res])
        };
    })
    console.log(array)
}

const handleImage = (e) => {
    let image = [...e.target.files];
    fileBase64(image);
}

<input type="file" multiple={true} onChange={handleImage}/>
```

Comment: you need to place your setArray logic in the `onloadend` callback.

Comment: The results are not available when using `console.log(array)` because the callback has not yet been invoked.

Comment: @MaartenDev so what's the solution? can you provide answer?

Comment: Move the `setArray(array)` call inside the `. onloadend` callback

Comment: @MaartenDev still return empty array, but after select second image it give me an array contains first selected image, not both, any solution? -- code updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to this `asynchronous` nature, state is being set i.e. `push` before data `urls` are set in array.

And that's the reason your your `array` return empty.

To fix it, you can use create `Promise` which gets resolved after load event of each file. And use `Promise.all` which would be resolved after each Promise has resolved and then use `setArray`:

```
fileBase64  = (img) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onerror = reject
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      resolve(fileReader.result)
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(img)
  })
}

handleImage = (e) => {
  let image = e.target.files;
  Promise.all(Array.from(image).map(this.readAsDataURL))
    .then((urls) => {
      setArray(urls)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing @pedram 's answer, there are a few things I did to make it work for my case.

1. instead of `.map(this.readAsDataURL)` I did `.map(fileBase64)` as we want to call this function on every single file when trying to upload multiple files collectively.
2. If you want to push the `urls` to an existing array, it should be `setArray((prevArray)=>[...prevArray,...urls])` where prevArray is the previous state of the array, due to useState being `asynchronous`.